# storing gziped strings in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, gzip

I'm referencing this [Store GZIP:ed text in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740819/store-gziped-text-in-mysql).

I want to store serialized sessions in the database (they are actually stored in a memcached pool but i have this as a failsafe). I am gziping/uncompressing from php.
I want to ask the following:

1) Is this a good move? I am doing this to avoid using `mediumtext` as the data may be bigger than `text`. I think/hope i will have a lot of sessions stored there. Is it, in this case, worth to gzip? Table is MyISAM.

2) Do i need to set the encoding of the table field to binary? Or only do that if i have a complete gziped file?

3) Is serializing a bad move, should i use `json_encode` instead (because of the smaller size i guess)?

Thanks,

Comment: Just a note: Even if you store some data that would fit perfectly into TEXT in MEDIUMTEXT instead, the difference in storage space would just be one additional byte as MEDIUMTEXT requires *L* + 3 bytes in opposite to *L* + 2 bytes that’s required for TEXT. See [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html) for more information.

Comment: How big is your average session? If it's only a 'few' bytes, you won't gain much in the way of storage savings, but lose a fair bit in (relatively) useless compression overhead.

Comment: @Mark B, well serialized it can easily be bigger than the text/blob limits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a MEDIUMBLOB field instead of MEDIUMTEXT. BLOBs have no encoding, as they are raw byte streams.